# How to know if Google PubSub subscriber has been disconnected

Tags: c#, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Google PubSub messaging service to pull published messages, using code sample from here (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#receive_messages):

```
SubscriptionName subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.FromProjectSubscription(projectId, subscriptionId);
SubscriberClient subscriber = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);

Task startTask = subscriber.StartAsync((PubsubMessage message, CancellationToken cancel) =>
{
    //Do something
    return Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
});
```

My question is - is it somehow possible to get notification that connection has been broken? Right now, if I disconnect internet, then reconnect again, my app simply stops receiving messages. It would be nice if some kind of exception would occur in such scenario. Any ideas on how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

StartAsync's returned Task will complete when an unrecoverable error occurs ([docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClient.html#Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_SubscriberClient_StartAsync_System_Func_Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_PubsubMessage_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_SubscriberClient_Reply___)). If your subscriber remains disconnected for an extended period of time, I would expect the Task to notify you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have tried that, but it does not work like that. As per documentation Task is completed when I call `StopAsync(CancellationToken)` but when network is disconnected(which I assume would be a worthy fault that should trigger task completion) it simply hangs on await and code after it never gets completed.

Comment: How long was your subscriber disconnected from the network? The client library might be retrying the connection under the hood, so it may take a while before it considers a disconnection to be an "unrecoverable error." I'd be surprised if the library does not eventually propagate this back to you; you could consider opening an issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues

Comment: My patience ended after 20 minutes. I haven't tried any longer. Yes, I suppose I will have to do as you say.